# iOS 13 MPRemoteCommandCenter disconnect after background mode

Tags: swift, avplayerviewcontroller, mpremotecommandcenter

Hi anyone run into issues when using AVPlayerViewController and set MPRemoteCommandCenter for control centre.  When the app goes to the background the video keeps playing but the control centre disconnects?

I used the example code from this post

https://medium.com/@quangtqag/play-a-video-and-continue-playing-audio-in-background-456ec139eae

works perfectly on ios 12 but in ios 13 when the app goes to the background, you can not control playback using control centre.